# How to fetch from getStaticProps and display on other pages?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have been using react's CSR data fetching methods mainly but recently have started on a project that required SSR so I started using Next.js

I have encountered an issue for which I'm unable to find an explanation for -

So I have an index.js file (which is considered as the parent file) - and this is the render part of the file

```
   return (
        <div className="container">
            <div id="tabs-with-content">
                <div className="tabs is-toggle is-toggle-rounded is-centered">
                    <ul className="tab-ul">
                        <li><a className="gamelinks">Valorant</a></li>
                        <li><a className="gamelinks">CS:GO</a></li>
                        <li><a className="gamelinks">Dota 2</a></li>
                        
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <section className="tab-content">
                        <Valorant/>
                    </section>

                    <section className="tab-content">
                       
                    </section>

                    <section className="tab-content">
                      
                    </section>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
```

Now the Valorant component which is considering as my child comp in this case -

```
function Valorant( {valres}) {
    
    return (
        <div className='container is-fluid'>
              <div className="columns is-multiline">
        {valres.map(q => (
          <div className="column is-half" key={q.id}>
            <div className="inner">
              <div className="inner__box">
                <Link href={'/upcoming/' + q.slug} key={q.slug}>
                  <a className="h2link" key={q.slug}>
                   {q.name}
                  </a>
                </Link>

                
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export async function getStaticProps() {

  const valresult = await fetch(`#`);
  

  const valdata = await valresult.json();
 

  return {
      props: { valres: valdata },
  };

}


export default Valorant;
```

The error message - `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`

```
 {valres.map(q => ( - This is the line caught in errors,
```

EDIT - So I did some debugging and have realised when I access my `valorant` page individually - I'm able to see the desired page however, I'm just unable to render this on the `index.js`

Comment: Can you log out `valdata` and update the question?

Comment: Hey, I'm unable to log the value to console as it sends me to the error page every time and my terminal displays the same error as well.

Comment: Well, have you commented out `valres.map` first, we need to see the data

Comment: @Enfieldli yeah just did that and it shows `undefined`.

Comment: Then it's your network issue, try to get the data first

Comment: Yes I get that but the issue is when I access the `valorant` page by going `index/valorant.js`, I'm able to get the results, However when I'm trying to display this Val component on` index.js` I get the undefined error.

Comment: Yo, at this point you know the cause, and should be fine fixing the network issue, happy coding anyway

Comment: Thank you for your help but no its not a network issue and I do not know the cause yet, thanks a ton regardless.

Comment: You're relying on `getStaticProps` to define `valres`, but that is only used for pages (i.e. routes). Instead you're importing the component itself, and not defining the prop at all. [Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props).

Comment: @JBallin so both my files are in the `pages` directory, I suppose when I import the component the `getStaticProps` doesn't return anything cause its SSR only? Is there any easy way around this without complicating the code base way too much and still stick to SSR